# Can ROS message declare as type list and set?

Tags: ros, add-message-files

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to define a ROS message,
and I try to declare one of them as type "list" and "set"
however it cannot catkin_make, it said that type "list" has nothing to depends on
Do anyone have experience in this situation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269151/can-ros-message-declare-as-type-list-and-set-?/) by [ChampionWay](https://answers.ros.org/users/31290/championway/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`list` and `set` are not natively supported field types in the [ROS msg idl](http://wiki.ros.org/msg).

Unbouned arrays would probably be equivalent to a list.

I don't think there is a way to get set semantics (ie: collections with a uniqueness guarantee on items) without user-level code (ie: msg producer and consumer) enforcing that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1